# Is there a way to decouple Laravel Eloquent models from Service or Controller level?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There is a simple Laravel Eloquent Model below:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

}
```

and it's normal to use repository pattern to work with model, like:

```php
use Product;

class ProductRepository implement ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(Product $model) 
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
        return $this->model->find($id);
    }

    ...

}
```

The controller use the repository to get `Prodcut` data:

```php
class ProductController extends Controller
{
   private $productRepository;

   public function __construct(ProductRepository $productRepository)
   {
       $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
   }

   public function getSomeInfoOfProduct($id)
   {
       $product = $this->productRepository->findById($id);

       return [
            'name' => $product->name,
            'alias' => $product->alias,
            'amount' => $product->amount,
       ];
   }
}
```

In the method `getSomeInfoOfProduct`, when I am deciding what kind of information should I return, I don't know there are how many properties the `$product` object has until I look at the schema of table `products` or migration files.

It's look like that the controller is tightly coupled with Eloquent models and the database. If one day, I store the raw data of products in Redis or other places, I still need to create a Eloquent model object, and fill in the object with the data from Redis.

So I am considering to create a pure data object to replace the Eloquent Model object, like below:

```
class ProductDataObject
{
    private $name;
    private $alias;
    private $amount;
    private $anyOtherElse;

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    ....
}
```

and let the repository return this object:

```php
use Product;
use ProductDataObject;

class ProductRepository implement ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(Product $model) 
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
        $result = $this->model->find($id);

        // use some way to fill properties of the object
        return new ProductDataObject(...);
    }

    ...

}
```

In the controller or service level, I can just look at `ProductDataObject` to get all information I need. And it also looks like easier to change data storage without affecting the controllers and services.

Does this way make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the Factory Pattern. You're kind of on the right track already. Basically you have a middle-man class that your Controller or Repository basically asks to supply them with the appropriate Model. Through either parsing conditions or a config file using .envs, it figures out which one to serve up, so long as anything it returns all implements the same Interface.